# hiding and unhiding a label based on time in the form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a code that hides and unhides based on time in Access VBA.

From my testing, it seems to skip `If` and proceed to `Else`.

I require a `Visible1` to appear during 07:30:00am to 11:59:59pm while `Visible2` to appear when during 00:00:00am to 07:30:00am. At any given time, either `Visible1` or `Visible2` should appear.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

Dim Visible1 As Boolean
Dim Visible2 As Boolean
Dim currentTime As String
Dim currentTimestring As String

currentTime = Time()
currentTimestring = Format(currentTime, "hh:mm:tt")

If currentTimestring >= TimeValue("07:30:00") And currentTimestring < TimeValue("00:00:00") Then

    Visible2 = True
    Visible1 = False

Else

    Visible1 = True
    Visible2 = False

End If

Me.Label22.Visible = Visible1
Me.Label11.Visible = Visible1
Me.Text10.Visible = Visible1
Me.Label13.Visible = Visible1
Me.Text12.Visible = Visible1

Me.Label23.Visible = Visible2
Me.Label16.Visible = Visible2
Me.Label18.Visible = Visible2
Me.Text15.Visible = Visible2
Me.Text17.Visible = Visible2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always handle date and time as *Date*, not text, not numbers, no expeptions. Thus:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim Visible1 As Boolean
    Dim Visible2 As Boolean
    Dim currentTime As Date

    currentTime = Time

    If currentTime >= TimeSerial(7, 30, 0) Then
        Visible1 = True
        Visible2 = False
    Else
        Visible1 = False
        Visible2 = True 
    End If

    Me.Label22.Visible = Visible1
    Me.Label11.Visible = Visible1
    Me.Text10.Visible = Visible1
    Me.Label13.Visible = Visible1
    Me.Text12.Visible = Visible1

    Me.Label23.Visible = Visible2
    Me.Label16.Visible = Visible2
    Me.Label18.Visible = Visible2
    Me.Text15.Visible = Visible2
    Me.Text17.Visible = Visible2

End Sub
```